# How to add page number qweb odoo without div class header and footer

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-15

I would like create report in odoo but the page information **not in** header or footer. I'm using `<span class="page"/> of <span class="topage"/>`. It's work if that code inside `<div class="header"/>` or `<div class="footer"/>`. But I get tricky case, that is page number must show in table or anywhere except footer or header. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: use custom logic for count pages and print on the report. like counter way.

Comment: can you give me example please?

Comment: You can't do counter for you need to write condition based on the page end. Better try , page must contain ten products and if exceed, it must move to next page and by using that you may achieve what you asked. Hope it helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the current page (`page`) and the number of pages (`topage`) outside of headers and footers is not yet available.

As [commented](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1889#issuecomment-649540718) by the wkhtmltopdf maintainer on june 2020

> Although this is obviously good to have, I'm not sure how it can be implemented right now -- the focus right now is upgrading the browser engine (read the project status), this will come after/if it gets upgraded.

The feature will come after upgrading the engine browser

You can see that feature requests like [global variable for page number](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4018) are still open